# vertical-align:middle for text in button

Tags: button, vertical-alignment, css

I have this layout:

[image: layout]

**My CSS**:

```
body {
     background: #e2eaed;
}
a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 30px;
     height: 62px;
     line-height: 62px;
     /* vertical-align: middle is not works  */
     background: #8dc73f;
     width: 132px;
     padding: 0 25px;
     font-size: 16px;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-left: 4px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
}
```

​When button has 1-line text, my code works well. But when button has 2-line text, like in the image above. The code text has big height, because I use the `line-height` property. I have tried `vertical-align` but it is not working.

Please, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJj2c/2/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vertical align only affects elements that displayed as table cells (or inline blocks, but effect on later is different). Those elements must not be floated.

```
a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;

  /* Reset */
  float: none;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

Comment: @Ozerich Table cells don't have margins. You may use transparent borders instead.

Answer (score 12):

Another method would be using [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes):

```
a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center; /* cross axis */
  justify-content: center; /* main axis */

  line-height: 1; /* reset */
}
```

You may need to add prefixes, see [browser support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJj2c/5/).