# Button's text vertical and horizontal alignment issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I have some buttons with text inside. What I'm trying to do is to align them to middle from vertical and horizontal.On the example I have 3 buttons (the left one is bigger in purpose)

When it a long text its placed on some rows on the middle of the button - it is not starting from the vertical middle but looks fine, but when I get short text it ("oneWord") then attached to the top side and all looks messy.

[image]

I read some exampels:

[How do I vertically align something inside a span tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732337/how-do-i-vertically-align-something-inside-a-span-tag)
[Button's text vertical align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487408/buttons-text-vertical-align)

[How do I vertically align something inside a span tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732337/how-do-i-vertically-align-something-inside-a-span-tag)

[vertical-align:middle for text in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901569/vertical-alignmiddle-for-text-in-button)

After all this I set my style to:

```
.spanContainer {
    height: 70px;
}

.spanContainer span {
    height: 70px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

After All the changes I'm getting those result:

On vertical side it is in middle(short and long text) - O.K, but on the horizontal for short text it start from the left side

[image]

The problem is that `display: table-cell` float it to left side for short text! 
How can I create those buttons so even if I have one word or a long text they all will start on the middle of the button on horizontal and vertical?

Answer (score 1):

Try the snippet below

CSS

```
.spanContainer {
    height: 70px;
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
}

.spanContainer span {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

Or don't use `width` on `spanContainer`, use some `padding` on the inner `span` instead

```
.spanContainer {
    height: 70px;
    display: table;
}

.spanContainer span {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="spanContainer">
  <span>something</span>
</span>
```

[First solution](http://jsbin.com/livawikaleju/1/edit?html,output) | [Second solution](http://jsbin.com/pomateborape/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: the `display: table` in `spanContainer` actually puts it in the middle but it re-size the width button, I cant use `width:100%` because those buttons are width fixed from from beginning

Comment: @Dima Well, your button may be 200px wide as well ;)

Comment: @Dima I added another solution; so, you don't have to specify `width` of the `spanContainer`, you may add some `padding` to the inner `span`

Comment: @Dima Actually you don't need even `padding` on the inner `span` but in that case how would you see that it's horizontally centered :) If there's no `width` or `padding`, the width of an element will be equal to the content inside.